# Property does not exist on type 'never' - on ngFor variable

Tags: angular, typescript

When I'm trying  to get responses from API, I use an ngFor for dynamically sorting my view. Here's the line of code:

```
  <agm-marker *ngFor="let httpResponses of response" [latitude]= "httpResponses.lat" [longitude]="httpResponses.lng"
        [agmFitBounds]="true">
```

To be more clear:

... `*ngFor="let httpResponses of response" [latitude]= "httpResponses.lat" [longitude]="httpResponses.lng"` ...

and it gives automatically the type of httpResponses as **never**. And because of that gives these errors below:

*error TS2339: Property 'lng' does not exist on type 'never'.*

*error TS2339: Property 'lat' does not exist on type 'never'.*

Can I declare any Typescript type on httpResponse in the Html file? The project works fine, I get the lat and lng values from httpResponses and display it, but however I constantly get these errors, I tried to declare type on httpResponses in component.ts file, it didn't change anything.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: the naming of your variables sounds like you meant to do `*ngFor="let response of httpResponses"`? to properly answer this question, please add the relevant information form the typescript file here.

Comment: Hello, I know it seems in the reverse way, but in the code i return my JSON responses to the response variable from my http service, and http service successfully assigns response variable with correct values. Also, even httpResponse is working in the correctly! But compiler gives the error, even if code is working correctly in the view. And then I'm doing ngFor thing in the html file. I'll add to the question if I can make my code simplifier.

Answer (score 6):

You should use *bracket notation* instead of *dot notation* for accessing property:

```
<agm-marker *ngFor="let httpResponses of response" [latitude]= "httpResponses['lat']" [longitude]="httpResponses['lng']"
        [agmFitBounds]="true">
```